# How can I join A with B and also B with C at one time?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three A, B, C tables.

How can I join A with B and also B with C at one time?

For example If I have these tables: Order, Product, User, I want be like this query:

```
SELECT Product.title, User.username, Order.id
FROM Order
/* with this condition: */
Order.ProductID = Product.ID
Product.UserID = User.ID
```

Comment: Give it a try yourself, then post your SQL here so we 1. Have a better idea what you mean, 2. Prove you have actually tried something.

Comment: Like this `SELECT
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON ...
INNER JOIN C ON ...`??

Comment: why can't you join and try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Product.title, User.username, Order.id
FROM Order
INNER join Product ON Order.ProductID = Product.ID
INNER JOIN user ON Product.UserID = User.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine joins in the from clause:

```
select * 
  from aaa a inner join bbb b
     on a.x = b.y
  inner join ccc c
     on b.x = c.y
```

Comment: where are relation between C and B ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from A a join B a on a.id = b.id /* condition for join*/ join C c on A.id = c.id /* condition for join*/ where ;//condition
```